# Larave validation: If added language already exists in this group_id then don't add

Tags: laravel

I have got an table with 2 foreign keys in it: ***language_id*** and ***group_id.***

Every new post i make gets a new ***group_id***, if i add a translation to a post it gets the same ***group_id*** as the selected post so no new ***group_id*** for that one.

So what i want to achieve is a validation rule that does this:

- If i want to add a translation with a other ***language_id*** it has to check if the ***language_id*** already exists but only in the same ***group_id***.

---

my table (SupportGuideTranslation):

**id / title / body / keywords / language_id / group_id / date**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use rule exists and add your `groupId` as a special condition.

```
[
    'language_id' => Rule::exists('SupportGuideTranslation', 'language_id')
        ->where(function ($query) use ($groupId) {
             return $query->where('group_id', $groupId);
        }),
]
```

Comment: Not certain how you would get $groupId just assumed i was there else elaborate and we can look into it. I guess this will get you further.

Comment: Ok i got it partly working, can u just tell me what $query is?

Comment: Oh sorry remove it from the function call, updated my answer